# EclipseLink/JPA: Multiple @DiscriminatorColumn annotations for Entity

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink

I'm looking for a way in EclipseLink to have two @DiscriminatorColumns on the same entity

My PostreSQL DB table is:

```
Dictionary
{
  id,
  object_type,
  attribute_type,
  translation
}
```

And classes are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dictionary")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="object_type", 
                     discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class DictionaryRow implements Serializable;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="info_type", 
                     discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class DictionaryAttribute extends DictionaryRow;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class DictionaryAttributeName extends DictionaryAttribute;
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I call for DictionaryAttributeName it will be resolved to SQL like:

```
select * from DICTIONARY where info_type = 1 and object_type = 0
```

But actually, it takes the DiscriminatorColumn from the DictionaryRow class, and DiscriminatorValue from the DictionaryAttributeName, resulting in the totally wrong SQL:

```
select * from DICTIONARY where object_type = 1
```

Is there a solution for this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JPA 2.0 specification, this is not possible:

> #### 11.1.10 DiscriminatorColumn Annotation
>
> For the `SINGLE_TABLE` mapping
>   strategy, and typically also for the
>   `JOINED` strategy, the persistence
>   provider will use a type discriminator
>   column. The `DiscriminatorColumn`
>   annotation is used to define the
>   discriminator column for the
>   `SINGLE_TABLE` and `JOINED`
>   inheritance mapping strategies.
>
> **The strategy and the discriminator column are only specified in the root
>   of an entity class hierarchy** or
>   subhierarchy in which a different
>   inheritance strategy is applied.

#### References

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 11.1.10 "DiscriminatorColumn Annotation"